# Calculate running time of thread in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I have calculated the running time of the two functions when running alone in main. The iterative version took 17s and the recursive version took 28s. Now I am trying to learn threads. What I was thinking was to create two threads with the different functions, start the timer before the calls to the thread and then afterwards check how long it would take, my hypothesis would be 28s until the both threads exit. However the problem is: **The program does not print the time and it prints: "Threads starting... after the threads exit.**

Questions:

**1. How can I modify the program to calculate the running time and display hopefully 28s**

**2. What am I doing wrong? A short explanation why my program is not working.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUMTHREADS 2
pthread_t threads[NUMTHREADS];
int sumArrayRec(int arr[], int size) {
    if (size == 1) {
        return arr[size - 1];
    } else {
        return arr[size - 1] + sumArray(arr, size - 1);
    }
}

int sumArrayIt(int arr[], int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

void *thread1(void *arg) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 999999999; x++) {
        sumArrayIt(arg, 10);
    }
}

void *thread2(void *arg) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 999999999; x++) {
        sumArrayRec(arg, 10);
    }
}




int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    time_t start = time(NULL);

    printf("Threads starting...");
    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, thread1, arr);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, thread2, arr);


    pthread_exit(NULL);
    printf("%.4f\n", (double)(time(NULL) - start));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_exit(NULL)` call in main() exits the main thread and thus the subsequent printf() is not executed at all.

Since you want to *wait* for the threads in order to calculate the time, you need to call `pthread_join()` instead on both (or the one thread you are interested in) threads.

Like:

```
pthread_join(thread[0], NULL);
pthread_join(thread[1], NULL);
printf("%.4f\n", (double)(time(NULL) - start));
```

The execution time(s) depend on the hardware, OS scheduling, other processes running on the system etc. So, you can't expect it to be a function of certain equation.

You should error check `pthread_create()` calls:

```
if (pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, thread1, arr)) {
    printf(stderr, "thread creation error<n");
    exit(1);
}

if (pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, thread2, arr)) {
    printf(stderr, "thread creation error<n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Also, add `return NULL;` statements (since you don't need to return value in your code) at the end your thread functions  as required by the Pthreads API.

Comment: Could you be more exact how I should call it? with arguments etc.

Comment: I have another question, why is the "Threads starting..." not printed previously to the threads starting?

Comment: Standard output is typically line buffered. Add a `\n` at the end of it in order to flush it.

Comment: You just need to check the return value of `pthread_create()` calls. I just updated. `pthread_create()` returns `0` on success and anything else is a failure - you can read the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) for details.